# Post has correct form values but validation fails

Tags: jquery, python, django, dajax

I am trying to collect my form data ( 3 ModelChoiceFields ) and validate them in my ajax.py to use the data for database operations. But when I click post, the data seems to be sent correctly as follows..

```
argv    {"form":"Branch=Maint&Env=Staging&Disc=Astronomy"}
Source
argv=%7B%22form%22%3A%22Branch%3DMaint%26Env%3DStaging%26Disc%3DAstronomy%22%7D
```

But the form doesn't get validated and on checking in Firebug, I get the following error for all three fields

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
>   choices.

My template (it has the necessary jquery and dajax files included as scripts)

```
 <form action="" method="post" id = "select_form">

 <div style = "color :white" class="field_wrapper">
      {{ form.as_p }}
 </div>

 <input type="button" value="Display Table" onclick="send_form();"/>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function send_form(){
        Dajaxice.modmap.dispTable(Dajax.process,{'form':$('#select_form').serialize(true)});
    }
 </script>
```

my ajax.py

@dajaxice_register

```
def dispTable(request, form):
    dajax = Dajax()
    form = BedSelectForm(deserialize_form(form))

    if form.is_valid():
        dajax.remove_css_class('#select_form input', 'error')
        dajax.alert("Form is_valid(), your username is: %s" %form.cleaned_data.get('Branch'))
    else:
        dajax.remove_css_class('#select_form input', 'error')
        for error in form.errors:
            dajax.add_css_class('#id_%s' % error, 'error')
        dajax.alert("Form is_notvalid(), your error is: %s" % form.errors)

    return dajax.json()
```

my form

```
class BedSelectForm(forms.Form):
Branch = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label = u'Branch',
    queryset = Result.objects.values_list('branch', flat =True).distinct(),
    empty_label = 'Not Specified',
    widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange' : "Dajaxice.modmap.updatecomboE(Dajax.process, {'optionB':this.value})"})
    )
Env = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label = u'Environment',
    queryset = Result.objects.values_list('environment', flat =True).distinct(),
    empty_label = 'Not Specified',
    widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange' : "Dajaxice.modmap.updatecomboD(Dajax.process, {'optionE':this.value})"})
    )
Disc = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label = u'Discipline',
    queryset = Result.objects.values_list('discipline', flat =True).distinct(),
    empty_label = 'Not Specified'

    )
```

My other dajax functions work fine. Just this one always enters the else block and prints the errors and I have no idea why when the data is being passed to it in the correct format.

I am referring to this example http://www.dajaxproject.com/fullform/ and trying to emulate almost similar behavior.

Comment: Why are you using a `values_list` query on your `ModelChoiceField` fields? That's probably your problem.

Comment: Because I only want the values of that particular tuple in that ModelChoiceField. Is there a better way to do it? How will using that query create a problem?

Comment: Because the result of the queryset must be models, not arbitrary strings. If you are choosing from models, use a queryset that will return just the models you want. If you are not choosing from models, do not use a `ModelChoiceField`.

Comment: Ok. So, forgive my naive question but, if I want to populate each ModelChoiceFeild with an individual tuple of the Model and at the same time I need it to have the entire model so that it validates as a form, how would I do this? Which query set would I use? I am looking the django docs and am confused. I am fairly new to this.

Comment: I can't tell what your query set would look like without seeing your models. It is odd to me that you have three different fields with such different names all trying to pick `Result` model instances - I suspect your model design may not well represent your intended uses. Are Discipline, Branch and Environment really all the same type of entity/record?

Comment: No, they're not. They're all CharFields. I am trying to put each one in a Select element and Environment updates based on Branch and Discipline updates based on Environment. Otherwise by default they all have all the values in that tuple in the database. I have separate dajax functions that do that and work as intended.

Comment: If they're fields, not models, you are not picking models - you are picking values of fields. A `ModelChoiceField` is what you use when the choice from the widget is itself a model instance, such as selecting an author from a search form in the class Django Publisher/Author/Book examples. It's not something you use to search over fields of a model, as you're discovering. You should probably just use a ChoiceField and search for matching `Result`s in your view.

Comment: You were entirely right. I hadn't understood fields properly. I used ChoiceField and my form validates. I populate it's value by overriding the init method.

Comment: If the correct choices depend on the request, yeah, overriding __init__ is a quite common approach.